# yandex-tank-api-client example doesn't work

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

I don't realize how *yandex-tank-api-client* example works. 
I've made following corrections in *tank-example.py*:
replaced (the error was otherwise)

```
84: tsk = tankapi.shoot(*cfg)
```

with

```
84: tsk = tankapi.shoot(*cfg, f)
```

where *f* - is the function:

```
def f(status, t):
    print "Status: %s" % status
```

I've replaced example's load.yaml file with my file:

```
- tanks: ['localhost']
  config: ./load.ini
  log_name: task-A
  download: ['*.log','*.ini']
  upload: ['*.ammo']
  expected_codes: [0]
```

Where *load.ini* is:

```
[DEFAULT]
use_caching = 0

[phantom]
phantom_path = /home/krylov/prj/yandex/phantom/bin/phantom
phantom_modules_path = /home/krylov/prj/yandex/phantom/lib/phantom
address=localhost:8000
rps_schedule=const(10, 10s)
; Headers and URIs for GET requests

header_http = 1.1
headers = /
          [Host: 127.0.0.1]
          [Connection: close]
uris = /
       /instances
       /datastore
       /datastore-indexes
```

After I run *yandex-tank-api-server* on *localhost* and [tank-example.py script](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank-api-client/blob/master/example/tank_example.py) test starts but it cannot leave the *configure* stage:

```
    2016-04-19 12:44:10,263 [DEBUG] Tank localhost: API returned code 200, contents:
{
    "status": "running", 
    "retcode": null, 
    "stage_completed": true, 
    "break": "configure", 
    "current_stage": "lock", 
    "tank_status": {}, 
    "failures": []
}
Status: 0
```

*tank.log* file ends by lines (you can [here](http://pastebin.com/Xz5V0MnF) full *tank.log*):

```
2016-04-19 12:44:00,287 [INFO] yandex_tank_api.worker Changing the next break from lock to configure
2016-04-19 12:44:00,288 [WARNING] yandextank.core.tankcore Lock file present: /var/lock/lunapark_1WgKl6.lock
2016-04-19 12:44:00,288 [DEBUG] root No process[3]: [Errno 3] No such process
2016-04-19 12:44:00,288 [DEBUG] yandextank.core.tankcore Lock PID 13895 not exists, ignoring and trying to remove
```

I'd like to understand why PID not exists. Does the example have an error?

Comment: I've opened an issue on this: https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank-api/issues/5